# VerifyAll() with Throws<T>() in Moq

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a Mock object whose method I'm trying to setup by throwing an Exception when executed, for a particular unit test case using the Moq framework.

```
var mockMySvc = new Mock<IMySvc>();

mockMySvc
   .Setup(x=>x.SomeMethod())
   .Throws<Exception>();

//Execution of some code

//At the assertions
mockMySvc.VerifyAll();
```

At runtime, the code complains about all the expections of `mockMySvc` not having been met despite the exception being thrown. Am I missing something or does the `.VerifyAll()` method not work with the `.Throws()` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your way of setting it up, but I always do it this way:

```
Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => myclass.SomeMethod());
```

This way you don't need to verify anything.

---

Based on your comment this is how you make sure the exception is thrown inside the method, so that you can check your code inside `catch` blocks.

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    _filmService.Setup(f => f.FindById(It.IsAny<int>())).Throws<Exception>();
    _filmController.Test();
    _filmService.Verify(f => f.Exists(It.IsAny<Film>()), Times.Once);
}
```

Actual code:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    try
    {
        _filmService.FindById(-1);
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        _filmService.Exists(null);
    }
    return View();
}
```

This is just an example I tested in my code and it works correctly.

Comment: Within the scope of the `someMethod()`, I'm having a try catch block. The try needs to throw an Exception to the catch block, and that's what I'm achieving through the setup/throws in my code. My code wouldn't return an exception. What you've asserted is an assumption that the method would throw an exception.

Comment: I understand now. Do you actually execute the `SomeMethod` method? Take a look here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/mock-exceptions-using-moq

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do- simulate an exception. I'm thinking I shouldn't be verifying an exception being thrown through VerifyAll(), but rather verifying that the right kind of exception was logged. Thank you! That helped in kind of understanding what I was doing wrong logically.

Comment: I added an example. I've just tested it and it works in my project.